# ACID transactions in HIVE table from pig script

Tags: hive, apache-pig, acid

Is it possible to perform ACID transactions in a Hive table from a Pig script?

As per the below link we can execute DDL statements on a hive table from a pig script: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2482

Answer (score 1):

As of now only DDL command are allowed i have tested this in `pig 0.16` version of `HDP 2.5.3`

you can create tables using hcat from PIG Grunt / Script:

override the property on the fly while executing pig script

```
pig -Dhcat.bin=/usr/bin/hcat test.pig
```

or
In your pig script or Grunt shell put this in the beginning

```
set hcat.bin /usr/bin/hcat;
```

inside grunt shell or script give command like:

```
sql create table database_name.table_name (col1 int, col2 string);
```